# Sudden decrease in number of pages indexed in Google

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot

One week ago, I updated the sitemap and pinged Google and other search engines to alert them to the change. However, the site now has lost like around 50 indexed pages (yes the site is my personal blog which i am only building up) in a week.

I have had done some research and came up with some possible contributing factors:

1. Google crawling had an issue (but this happened back in 2010-2011).
2. Something may have been wrong with the sitemap that was submitted to Google. (Although, I have checked this and there are no broken links.)

Can anyone point me as to what might be the reason for this? Also, how can I go about re-indexing the pages ?

This is similar to other questions on this site, but I have gone through [Why is the number of pages on my website indexed by Googlebot decreasing?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4403/why-is-the-number-of-pages-on-my-website-indexed-by-googlebot-decreasing) and [Why the number of indexed pages decreased for a "site:" search](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18287/why-the-number-of-indexed-pages-got-decreased) and neither addresses a situation like this.

Update : The site is continously going down in pages indexed and now it sits at a 100 pages less and in total there were only 300..:(

Comment: How are you measuring the number of indexed pages?  Using a "site:" search, using webmaster tools "Index Status", or using webmaster tools "Crawl" -> "Sitemaps"?

Comment: When you updated your sitemap, was it because you had changed the URLs on your site, or was it only regenerated to update it with your latest content?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller : Thankyou for replying. 1. Using "site:myurl" in google and also using an add-on in mozilla. 2. Sitemap was old, i updated it using free sitemap creator and uploaded. Also pinged google after uploaded. It first updated around 300 urls and then dropped to 250 in last one week..

Comment: The only reliable method for determining how much is indexed is to log into Webmaster Tools.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller : Okay, so the "site:domain.com" is not accurate i guess.. I will look into this trend in coming days and update here..Kindly do update if there is anything else that i should be checking out..

Comment: @RoyMJ After edits, this might not be a duplicate of the linked question. However, there are really too many possible reasons to speculate, and questions regarding site reviews are unfortunately [off-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. I can suggest going through Google Webmaster Tools and looking for errors (e.g., crawl errors, DNS errors, duplicate content issues, etc...). Good luck!