# How can I get Google to index all my pages when only 10% are currently indexed?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

Google is indexing parts of the site www.findinplumbing.com.
If you use `site:` search, you get 5000 results. BUT: that is by far not enough. The site has around 11000 pages.

In Google search console it says:

> 11.240 URLs transferred 1.386 indexed URLs

so 10% ONLY.

Well now what? What can I do so Google indexes all 11,000 pages?

I provided a sitemap.xml here http://www.findingplumbing.com/xmlsitemap/sitemap.xml and a page that I triggered in Google search tools to have indexed manually and recursively that contains all pages (http://www.findingplumbing.com/google/allpages). Still, nothing happens.

I provided even a page where ALL pages appear as direct links. Still: not all pages get indexed. What is the problem? Now: this page went live in November 2016. That is 2 months ago now. And only 10% are indexed... very little

Comment: I would have thought we would have answered this question already, but I can't find a duplicate.  We have [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content) but it doesn't address the issue of partially indexed sites.   Also similar: [Why is the number of pages on my website indexed by Googlebot decreasing?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4403/why-is-the-number-of-pages-on-my-website-indexed-by-googlebot-decreasing)

Comment: Increase the quality of the other 90%?

Comment: FYI: I have yet to encounter a larger website with all pages indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the pages on your site are of extremely poor quality and provide little to no content to users at all. Google cares about user experience and their mechanisms can easily detect poor quality content.

They basically said, "we can stop here because this is ongoing we can't index 1 million generic probably automated pages". Your product pages already exist and are indexed and match other pages on the web, they simply choose not to disply in their index because other better quality content already exists and your pages are below the threshold of even being considered good enough for anyone to read or interact with and that is why most of them don't show up. They hate [little or no original content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66361?hl=en) and probably consider the fact that you [scrape content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721312?hl=en). This means that your site has red flags all over and is sort of blacklisted. Which means it will take a lot of hard work to start getting pages even of good quality content indexed.

Being the fact that your pages only contain a product tittle that matches another website with the same information but their sites is of quality, they simply consider your website as a duplicate content website or a scraper and they don't index or work with scrapers.

Product pages normally include descriptions and yours, not even that. They are getting smarter and smarter every day..

> Although Google indexes billions of webpages and are constantly
> working to increase the number of pages they include, they don't
> guarantee that they'll crawl all of the pages of a particular site.
> Google doesn't crawl all the pages on the web, and they don't index
> all the pages they crawl. It's perfectly normal for not all the pages
> on your site to be indexed.

In my opinion you have quite a good average of pages index by their
search engine.

> While they can't guarantee that all pages of a site will consistently
> appear in in their index, they offer guidelines for maintaining a
> Google-friendly site. Check the following:
> support(.)google(.)com/webmasters/answer/34441?hl=en
>
> Source: google(.)com/webmasters/answer/34441?hl=en

I would suggest as @Martijn said. Work on your pages, develop their credibility, stop generating or creating those types of pages. Make your site look authentic and give authority to in every page with quality genuine and original content. And that is the basics that you need to do in order to get your pages indexed.  Right now it simply looks like a site that scrapes pages. User experience is a priority for Google and your site does not offer any good on that in those pages.